# Combination of URLRequest +JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, json, asihttprequest

What would be the best option for:

- URL Request

  1. NSURLConnection
  2. ASIHTTPRequest
  3. AFNetwork
- JSON Parsing

  1. NSJSONSerialization
  2. SBJSON

I have picked ASIHTTPRequest+NSJSONSerialization, but I am not quite sure! Any idea(s) or suggestion(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features wise, AFNetworking > ASIHTTPRequest > NSURLConnection. ASIHTTPRequest is not supported anymore. It's a closed project. NSURLConnection is apple-provided so it's barebones. AFNetworking is still an active project and from the talk of my colleagues here in SO, it's getting better.

NSJSONSerialization is Apple-provided and SBJSON is third party again.SBJSON gives your a better/easier interface to convert data objects in either formats (Foundation <--> JSON).

BUT - things majorly depend on what you want to get out of your project and what the requirements are. Each of these projects has it's advantages and disadvantages. You just need to research each of these frameworks and choose the best that suits your project. Also, there are tons of resources here on SO that help you decide what to pick.

Comment: I have used ASIHTTPRequest in ios 6, but it is working. What do you mean it is not supported anymore, could you elaborate please?

Comment: The project is closed. It is not being enhanced to work with upgrading iOS versions. It doesn't support ARC. It's just lying there for people to use, but is not being taken care of anymore.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial in that example they are using ASIHTTPRequest. Is there any specific reason, why did not they NSURLConnection?

Comment: I haven't seen that example in detail, but I'm guessing it's just because ASIHTTP offers more flexibility in asynchronous data transfer than NSURLConnection can.